# Use github action to push specific file extentions to azure storage account

Tags: github, github-actions

I am, for the first time, working with github action.
What i need to achieve, is when a push a project with different files on it(for example: json files and txt files), i would like github action to push only the files .txt to a azure storage account.

Now, my github pipeline is structured as follow and it working:

```
on: [push]

env:
  AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: <resource-group-name>
  BLOB_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME: <storage-account-name>
# name: AzureARMDeploy

jobs:

    modules:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:

      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: Checkout source code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Deploy to storage using CLI
        uses: azure/CLI@v1
        with:
          azcliversion: latest
          inlineScript: |
            ls
            # show azure account being used
            az account show
            # az storage account upload
            az storage blob upload-batch --account-name ${{ env.BLOB_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }} -d '<storagename>' -s <folder>
            az storage blob upload-batch --account-name ${{ env.BLOB_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }} -d '<storagename>' -s ./<folder name>/<file extentions>
```

In the first `upload-batch` i am able to copy all the content folder to my azure storage account.

in the last upload-batch:

```
az storage blob upload-batch --account-name ${{ env.BLOB_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }} -d '<storagename>' -s ./<folder name>/<file extentions>
```

i tried with:
`-s ./<folder name>/*.txt` but i get an error:

```
 ValidationError: incorrect usage: source must be an existing directory
```

And i am pretty sure that the error is due to the `*.txt`, i was wondering if any of you know about any solution how to implement this logic.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--pattern` flag

```
--pattern

The pattern used for globbing files or blobs in the source. The supported patterns are '*', '?', '[seq]', and '[!seq]'. For more information, please refer to https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fnmatch.html.
```

So it would be like

```
az storage blob upload-batch --account-name ${{ env.BLOB_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }} -d '<storagename>' -s './<folder name>' --pattern "*.txt"
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much mate. You are a leggend

Comment: @NaydenVan Can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?

Comment: Sorry, is there any way how i can push to a storage only the json files from differend subdirectories? i keep having an error and i cant find a way to solve it